# how to detect UICollectionView update or reload in customize UICollectionViewFlowLayout?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewflowlayout

my customize `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` like this:

```
override func prepare() {
    super.prepare()

    // compute all cell frame
}
```

prepare() will be called after any data changed(reload, insert, delete) and all cell frame will be recomputed.

so how to detect update or reload for reducing compute time?

Comment: Do you mean you don't want recompute if not needed? Can you implement a `isRecomputationNeeded` and test that first in `prepare`? Like `if !isRecomputationNeeded() { return }`

Comment: @MedoPaw yes, but how to implement `isRecomputationNeeded`?  From documentation `prepare(forCollectionViewUpdates: updateItems)` is called when every update(deletes/inserts...) to the `UICollectionView`, but this method is called after `prepare()`.

Comment: Yes `prepare` is called every time, but according to documentation the default implementation does nothing. So if you can implement `isRecomputationNeeded` and put the `if !isRecomputationNeeded() { return }` code at the beginning, then the recomputation does not happen if not needed.

Comment: And it's for you to decide each time whether the recomputation is needed. It's related to your business logic. *e.g.* Say if `dataSource` stays the same, it shouldn't need recomputation right? But that's for you to decide actually.